# Are we drowning in package managers?

Tags: apt, package-management, pip, npm

The current trend is to use language-oriented package manager, such as [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) or [bower](http://bower.io/) for javascript, [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) for python, [gems](https://rubygems.org/) for ruby and [so on](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111045/distro-with-pip-and-npm-as-package-managers).

As I understand the need for a dependency manager when you want to deploy your application (they all can do that). I don’t get it when you need a new package-manager for installing local app on your system. I think you should always rely on your default package manager.

Why some tools are only distributed with pip, or npm and not with system package manager as apt, rpm, or yum ?

Comment: http://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: @jscott love that one !

Answer (score 4):

I found Chris Siebenmann's article quite insightful: [Why people keep creating new package managers](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/tech/WhyNewPackageManagers)

It boils down to a conflict of perspectives/interests between the sysadmins/OS maintainers, who want a stable and uniform environment "in" their operating system, and programmers/languages, who want faster iterations and a uniform package management across multiple operating systems.